# How to make empty cells in table, using Underscore template - when there is no data?

Tags: jquery, templates, underscore.js-templating

I receive 8 data from backend. client request me to show the datas as 7 in row. when i do the `each` iteration, I can open a `tr` according to the requirment. I am getting the first row as fine. But in the second `row` i have only one `td`.

my question is when there is no data from server... how can i make empty cells in table and close the `tr`?

[here is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c1bufvpk/)

my js conditional code:

```
<tbody>
                <% _.each(schemeCodeDetails, function (item, index) { %>
                    <%= index % 7 == 0 ? '<tr>' : null %>
                            <td>
                                <%= item.schemeCode %>
                            </td>
                <% }) %>
```

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/c1bufvpk/1/

Comment: Yes. But is this correct way to do it?